# Передача нескольких .txt файлов в качестве параметров при запуске через консоль

Tags: c#

Необходимо создать приложение на c#, которое будет запускаться через консоль с параметрами (именами файлов). Несколько файлов нужно считать и объединить данные в массив. При запуске приложения через cmd, имена любых файлов передаются как параметры. Как сделать, чтобы приложение не обращалось к файлам, а считавала их как параметры? Подскажите пожалуйста!

```
string[] strList_1 = File.ReadAllLines(@"/Users\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\1.txt");
string[] strList_2 = File.ReadAllLines(@"/Users\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\2.txt");
Console.WriteLine("First file: " + strList_1.Length + " elements");
Console.WriteLine("Second file: " + strList_2.Length + " elements");
```

Comment: А какие проблемы вы видите? Как вы пробовали и что не получилось?

Comment: Получилось только через программу обращаться к файлам, а мне нужно, чтобы при написание в командной строке exe файла и наименования файлов, он загружал их в программу и обрабатывал

Answer (score 1):

Создайте новый проект по шаблону консольного приложения. При этом студия автоматически добавит в проект файл следующего содержания:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Обратите внимание, статический метод `Main` — это точка входа в приложение, он принимает массив `string[] args`, внимание, **это и есть набор аргументов, с которыми приложение было запущено**. Просто переберите их и обработайте как нужно, это в полне могут быть имена файлов или что угодно что вам нужно. Ну и не забудьте обработать случаи некорректного ввода.

Comment: Это я понимаю, у меня помимо файлов в командной строке задаются другие ключи static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (input == "-i")
            { .. Здесь нужно считать файлы с расширением txt, их может быть любое количество, как это прописать я не знаю

Comment: @user351500, но в твоем же примере ты не из командной строки получаешь, а непосредственно от полльзователя